# using next() to manually generate items one at a time (python 3)

Tags: python

I'm trying to manually step through a windows folder/ file structure using os.walk().  I'm working in Jupyter Notebooks.
If I execute:

```
next(os.walk(path))
```

I get a result that makes sense the first time, but then I keep getting exactly the same response every time I execute that statement.
However, if I do:

```
g=os.walk(path)
next(g)
```

then I do get the next logical record each time I execute:

```
next(g)
```

Note that both:
    type(g) and type(os.walk(path))
return 'generator'.

Please explain why 'next' behaves differently depending on whether it is applied to g or os.walk()

Thank you--

Answer (score 4):

Because every time you call `os.walk`, you get a *new* generator which starts at the top (or bottom with `topdown=False`). If you call `next` repeatedly on the *same* generator, on the other hand, you will iterate through all the values it generates.

In principle, this is no different than the operation of `range`. `next(range(42))` always produces 0. If that were not the case, `range` would be pretty useless, since there would be no way of knowing where a given `for i in range(x):` iteration would start.

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk` is a generator function. Each time it is called it returns a new iterable object.

When you write `g=os.walk(path)`, you create a new iterable object named `g`.  Each time you call `next(g)` the iterator takes one step.

When you write `next(os.walk(path))` you create a new iterable object but do not give it a name.  You have called it once but have no way of calling it again because it has not been bound to a name.  That's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `os.walk(path)` you create a *new* generator, one which is ready to walk through all the nodes accessible from the path, starting at the first one.

When you do `next(os.walk(path))` you

1. Create a new generator.
2. Extract the first item from the generator using `next`.
3. Drop the generator which subsequently gets garbage collected and disappears, along with any knowledge of how many items you have extracted from it.
4. Repeating `next(os.walk(path))` takes you back to point 1, which gets you a fresh generator starting at the first element yet again.

When you do `g = os.walk(path); next(g)` you

1. Create a new generator.
2. Store the generator in the variable `g`. This prevents it from being garbage collected, and preserves its internal state.
3. Extract the first element from the generator (using `next`) and advance its internal state.
4. Repeating `next(g)` gets you the next item in the generator you just used.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand better now, but am still a little confused, just at a higher level.

Comment: Using the above example, os.walk(path), os.walk(path).__iter__(), and g all return <generator object>.  In contrast, __iter__() on an iterable distinguishes itself from the iterable by returning <iterator> - so you can tell the difference between the iterable and the iterator.  For the generator, both the generator and the iterator seem to return <generator>.  Shouldn't there be some way to distinguish the two? @Paul Cornelius

Comment: @KevinC Firstly, don't use `whatever.__iter__()`: prefer `iter(whatever)`. `iter(...)` retrieves the iterator coresponding to the iterable you feed it. If what you feed it *already is* an iterator, then `iter` just returns its argument. Generators (the `<generator object>`s you mention, are just one possible way of implementing iterators. In other words, don't read too much into your observation above: *iterator* and *generator* are one and the same, to a first-order approximation, and that's what matters here.